# jQuery plugin for rotating elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html, rotation

```
<div id="rotate">
  <img .. />
  <img .. />
</div>
```

Is it possible to rotate parent `div` only (`$("#rotate").rotate()`) and all its children will also rotate with it? If yes, then please suggest the plugin which will do this for me or, if not, then please suggest the workaround for this.

Comment: Rotate in what way? Like a slider/carousel, or using CSS transforms, or something entirely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("#rotate, #rotate img").rotate();
```

Comment: SInce jQuery core has no .rotate() function, how exactly does this work?

Comment: @j08691 as much I know jquery rotate plugin do this job look here, http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: thanks for answer but is there any way by which only $("#rotate").rotate() ( or any other plugin) will do this job

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is set a style on the element:

```
$('#rotate').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
```